# Python else statement doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can anybody help me with my code. I wrote a little program just so that I can learn some of the functions and what is going on. Let me show you my code.

```
print "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!"
original = raw_input("Word Please?")
if len("original") > 0:
    print original
else:
    print "empty"
```

When len(original) is 0 it should print "empty" but nothing happens, can someone explain what I am doing wrong please?
Thank you

Comment: No, it's working exactly as expected.

Comment: That is main problem of work with computer - it does only what you say it to do, not what you want it to do.

Comment: I doubt if there should be double quote in the if condition!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`len("original")` will compute the LENGTH of the string `"original"` (which is `8`) and hence that `if` condition will always be `True`.

Here, since, you want to compute the length of the variable original, you should write 
`len(original)` instead of `len("original")`.

Answer (score 5):

Your `if` conditions is always `True`, as instead of passing the variable you passed it a string. `"original"` is a string not the variable `original`.

```
if len("original") > 0:  # 8 > 0  always True
```

it should  be :

```
if len(original) > 0:
```

or simply :

```
if original:            # as bool('') --> `False`
```

Answer (score 2):

You're checking if the string `"original"` s length is greater than 0, which leads the if/else to work exactly as expected.

What you should do is

```
if len(original) > 0:
   print original
else:
   print "empty"
```

or preferrably the more pythonic way (if your `original` would be an empty string and not a series of spaces.)

```
if original:
    print original
else:
    print "empty"
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition you are checking will be always `True` - `if len("original") > 0:`

since `len("original") > 0` will always be `True` because you are checking whether a string enclosed in `"original"` will always have its length --8 and the else part wont be executed.

You can modify your code like

```
if len(original) > 0:  #or if original:
    print original
else:
    print "empty"
```

Comment: It should be `if len(original) > 0`.